# How to Access data on cuda by openGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda

I have generally learned OpenGL Interoperability with CUDA, but my problem is like this:

I have a lot of arrays, some for vertex, some for norm and some for alpha value alone, and some pointers to these arrays on device memory (something like dev_ver, dev_norm) which are used in kernel. I have already mapped the resource and now I want to use these data in shaders to make some effects. My rendering code is like this:

```
glUseProgram                (programID);

glBindBuffer                (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer_0);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, _data_on_cpu_0, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer       (0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

glBindBuffer                (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer_1);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, _data_on_cpu_1, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer       (1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

glBindBuffer                (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer_2);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, _data_on_cpu_2, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer       (2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray   (0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray   (1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray   (2);

glDrawArrays                (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, _max_);

glDisableVertexAttribArray  (0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray  (1);
glDisableVertexAttribArray  (2);
```

However, now I have no _data_on_cpu_, is it still possible to do the same thing ? The sample in cuda 6.0 is something like this:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posVbo);
glVertexPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, normalVbo);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(float)*4, 0);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, totalVerts);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

I don't exactly understand how this could work and what to do in my case.

By the way, the method I have used is to cudaMemcpy the dev_ to host and do the render like usual, but this is obviously not efficient, because when I do rendering I again send the data back to GPU by OpenGL (if I'm right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what your asking for, you mention CUDA yet none of the code you have posted is CUDA specific. I'm guessing `vertexbuffer_2` contains additional per vertex information you want to access in the shader?

OpenGL calls are as efficient as you will get it, they aren't actually copying any data back from device to host. They are simply sending the addresses to the device, telling it where to get the data from and how much data to use to render.

You only need to fill the vertex and normal information at the start of your program, there isn't much reason to be changing this information during execution. You can then change data stored in texture buffers to pass additional per entity data to shaders to change model position, rotation, colour etc.

---

When you write your shader you must include in it;
`attribute in vec3 v_data;` (or similar)

When you init your shader you must then;

```
GLuint vs_v_data = glGetAttribLocation(p_shaderProgram, "v_data");
```

Then instead of your;

```
glBindBuffer                (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer_2);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, _data_on_cpu_2, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer       (2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
```

You use;

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray   (vs_v_data);
glBindBuffer                (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer_2);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, _data_on_cpu_2, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer       (vs_v_data, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
```

This should let you access a `float3` inside your vshaders called `v_data` that has whatevers stored in `vertexBuffer_2`, presumably secondary vertex information to lerp between for animation.

---

A simple shader for this that simply repositions vertices based on an input tick

```
#version 120
attribute in float tick;
attribute in vec3 v_data;
void main()
{
    gl_Vertex.xyz = mix(gl_Vertex.xyz, v_data, tick);
}
```

---

If you want per entity data instead of/in addition to per vertex data, you should be doing that via texture buffers.

---

If your trying to access vertex buffer obj data inside kernels you need to use a bunch of functions;

`cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer()` This will give you a resource pointer to the buffer, execute this once after you initially setup the vbo.

`cudaGraphicsMapResources()` This will map the buffer (you can use it in CUDA but not gl)

`cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer()` This will give you a device pointer to the buffer, pass this to the the kernel.

`cudaGraphicsUnmapResources()` This will unmap the buffer (you can use it in gl, but not CUDA)

Comment: Robadob, thank you for your answer. The part of registering and mapping data to cuda is in another place and I just omitted it. I understand your code and I am doing in a similar way at first (I'm using OpenGL 3.3), but as I asked, now the data is on device, so I don't have **_data_on_cpu_2** at hand. Of course if I want, I can send it from device to host, but that takes time. What I have on host is only a pointer like **dev_data_on_gpu_2**(to launch kernel).

Comment: You want to access your vbo data inside a kernel?
I've added info about this to my answer.

Comment: I'm not accessing vbo data inside a kernel, but the other way around. The data is always in my gpu, I seldom send it from gpu to cpu. I just need to visualize it, so what I want to do is to access data inside gpu by OpenGL(if it is possible). Or I misunderstand some important concepts ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? with cuda/graphics, perhaps knowing that on a higher level will help me understand what your after.

Comment: I am using cuda to do some fluid simulation, so at first I initialize the data on CPU and then send the data to GPU. On the gpu side, after each step of simulation, I have new position & states for each node. Then I use the new states to calculate things like normal (e.g. using marching cubes), this is also done by cuda. By now no data is sent from GPU to CPU, but what I'm trying to do next is to visulize the fluid by using OpenGL. I have already succeeded in sending the data from gpu to cpu and use openGL as usual, but I want to know whether it's possible to use the data in gpu directly.

Comment: By my understanding, you have some data in cpu mem, you call OpenGL functions, the data is automatically sent to gpu for the opengl pipeline. But in my case the data is already in gpu mem.

Comment: When you call `glBindBuffer`, `glRenderTriangles` etc you are simply passing pointers to the gpu, you aren't transferring your data. You simply say render w triangles using vertices in buffer x, normals in buffer y etc. This is all that is sent to the GPU, not the actual content of the buffers. It is not possible to trigger these methods from the GPU.

Comment: Unless that the data is already inside your ddr5 gpu memory, you have to send data there, or the gpu can do nothing for you (the reason is simple: gpu can not process data on cpu memory). When I call **glBindBuffer** , it is like what you said, but if the data changed (e.g. by your cpu function), you have to update it, right ? So I use **glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, _data_on_cpu_2, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)** to update the data.

Comment: If your changing the data on CPU yes you must call glBufferData again to update the data in the buffer, however you've been saying that your changing this data with CUDA.

Comment: Yes, that is my question. Can I use data stored in gpu mem but not cpu mem and how.

Comment: Get a device pointer to the buffer using the methods at the bottom of my answer, then memcpy or use a kernel to write to them.